# How to connect sensor devices to IOTF using API KEYS

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

I am doing an android application, I'd like to know how to connect sensor devices/applications to Bluemix IoTF using API keys, by saying that I just want to minimize the registration task from client side(sensor devices)as much as possible. I know how to register devices with deivce Id,token and authentication manually. but I just like to know that is there any other easy way around to do it. It would be great If I got some one shed light on this from scratch. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rich set of REST based APIs available at:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/devices/api.html

and fully documented here:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#/

One can use excellent REST based testing tools such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for REST testing.

The reason I mention the REST APIs is that they provide a way for scripting or automating the registration of devices.  There is an API called "Add device" that, when called, will register a new device instance of a specific device type against your IoT Foundation instance.

I could imagine a new device that knows it is not registered executing a self registration request to define itself as a new device type.  What I would next suggest is that you read the links above and see if they make sense.  If they answer your question fully, great.  If not, simply post a new question that is specifically targeted at a specific areas and we'll be watching this set of tags and respond back as quickly as we can.